# Place CodeIgniter's Config Files out of 'application/'

Tags: php, codeigniter, config

I'm trying to move the config directory in the root folder for my CMS.
It will be easier for users to update and edit the config.
Everything I tried gave me an error, so I do not think the right way is to edit a bunch of system files.
I read about Environments, and the ability to create several config folders, but them do not allow me to place one in the root folder, do they?
If there is a known method how to do this, please help me ;) .

Comment: you can keep your file at root and include the file in `codeigniter's` config file using php `include` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `config.php` at root level and You can use `include` this file in `codeigniter`'s `config.php`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This keeps me motivated to help others ;)